# LaTeX table - Multirow Issues

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow

I'm not very familiar with LaTeX and I'm having issues formatting a table. I'm using `longtable` and `mulitrow`, and the following portion of code is causing issues:

```
REQ-015 & \multirow{1}{=}{Verified in Ansys dynamic analysis.} 
        & \multirow{1}{=}{Use of shakers with slip table and head 
          expander for in-plane and out-of-plane vibration 
          respectively. Use of strain gauges and accelerometers 
          for measurements.} \\
  \cline{1-1} 
  REQ-016 & & \\
  \hline
    REQ-017 &Verified through static load testing in Ansys. & \\
  \hline
```

What's happening is the text in the merged rows for REQ-015 and REQ-016 of column 3 are overflowing down into REQ-017 as seen here:

[image]

Is anyone able to help me with this? The table has other rows like this that aren't causing issues but I can't seem to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I can't think of a situation in which `\multirow{1}` makes sense (1 is not multi). Because the tight column cells occupy 4 lines, `\multirow{4}` would make more sense. Please try that.

Comment: Please tell us more about how you've defined the `longtable` environment at hand.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear to me what you what to achieve, but here is my solution with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption={My long table}
  ]{
  colspec={lp{5cm}p{7cm}},
  vlines, 
  vspan=even,
  }
  \hline
  & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Verified in Ansys dynamic analysis. & \SetCell[r=4]{l} Use of shakers with slip table and head expander for in-plane and out-of-plane vibration respectively. Use of strain gauges and accelerometers for measurements. \\
  REQ-015 & & \\
  \cline{1-1} 
  REQ-016 & & \\
  & & \\
  \hline 
  REQ-017 &Verified through static load testing in Ansys. & \\ 
  \hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{| l | p{5cm} | p{7cm} |}
  \hline
   & \multirow{2}{=}{Verified in Ansys dynamic analysis.} & \multirow{4}{=}{Use of shakers with slip table and head expander for in-plane and out-of-plane vibration respectively. Use of strain gauges and accelerometers for measurements.} \\*
  REQ-015 & & \\* \cline{1-1}
  REQ-016 & & \\*
   & & \\
 \hline REQ-017 &Verified through static load testing in Ansys. & \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To prevent page breaks inside one "unit", it is best to replace the `\\` with `\\*` in places where you don't want a pagebreak.